# why does the class created with type(<name>,<bases>,<dict>) , isnt available with the same 'name' value, when assigned to different variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Hello i am learning about meta classes, and i was experimenting with type methods to  create the class dynamically

here i have created a class normally

```
class C:
     pass
```

when ever i printed the **name**, **class** attribute it prints class name and type meta class

```
C.__name__
C.__class__
```

it prints

```
C
<class type>
```

when ever i alias the class with some thing like
`s = C` i was still able to access the class `C()` like this

now i have created a class with type method

`xx = type('Bar',(),{})`

and then printed the xx.**name** & xx.**class**  and the output is

```
Bar
<class type>
```

and i have also created a instance of it
`y = xx()`
and printed `type(y)`
i got output as `<class '__main__.Bar'>`

but whenever i tried to access the class Bar by `Bar()` it says

```
 Bar()
NameError: name 'Bar' is not defined
```

can any one tell why name Bar() is not available in my namespaces

Comment: Because in `xx = type('Bar',(),{})` you bound it to the name `xx` in your namespace, not `Bar`.

Comment: if we take some thing like type(10) is shows <class int> we can access the int() class right, so why cant i access the Bar class now when it is of type __main__.Bar()

Comment: `int` is a Python builtin - it's always in your namespace. `class C: pass` is like doing `C = type('C', (), {}`, so it binds `C` into your namespace. I can understand why based  on that, your assumption is that the act of giving a class a name is what brings it into the namespace. But it isn't so: `class C` gives the class a name and also binds it to the namespace, but `type('C', (), {})` only gives it a name.

Comment: Here's a reference in the docs: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#type Note that the equivalent of `class X: a=1` isn't just `type('X', (), dict(a=1))`, but `X = type('X', (), dict(a=1))`.

Comment: @slothrop i have one more question i have a `class R: pass`  & `R=None`,  `r = R()` says none type object is not callable, but when i doing some thing like this `class Hai: f=10` & `h=Hai()` `Hai=None` i can still access `h.f` gives `20` could you tell why even though  i have made the class Hai to refer to `None` , then why the object `h` referencing to it automatically destroyed, after that i have created something like `hh=Hai()` and then printed `hh.f` it didnt give raise to any error but printed empty spaces, so is the `Hai` still available or not , due to strong reference

Comment: The class object which you originally assigned to `Hai` can't be garbage-collected, because the instance `h` still has a reference to that class object. btw when I do what you describe, `hh=Hai()` throws an error, "'NoneType' object is not callable"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/254959/discussion-between-sriharsha-and-slothrop).

Comment: sorry my mistake `hh= Hai()` gave to Nonetype object not callable

Answer (score 0):

The name class for Bar type is xx

Rename xx = type('Bar',(),{})

by

Bar = type('Bar',(),{})

and you can write now : Bar()

<**main**.Bar at 0x1fa2d17cc40>

Comment: thank you ,my question is then class of type Bar should be available right?? like in type(10) <class int> we can access the int class , so thats my question